# Plot appearance changes based on RStudio window size and plotting method

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a distribution in R using the package vioplot; my plot consists of a scatterplot of points with violin plots (representing 'bins' of these points) plotted over the top of the scatterplots.

However, different methods of plotting my data result in slightly different characteristics in the plot. If all the violin plots are plotted using a loop, the violin plot tails will stretch down to the lowest points, but if plotted individually, the violin plot tails won't reach to the outliers. Additionally, resizing the plot window (and then re-plotting) also changes how the tails of the violin plots appear.

Because I'm getting these differing plots, I'm wondering how to tell which plot is the correct representation of the data, and how to produce a consistent result. I've used the 'range' and 'coef' arguments in vioplot to make the plots more consistent, but this hasn't worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong, but I think the violin itself is not really that defined and just an easy-to-look-at data representation. The boxplot on the other hand (which is plotted as well with vioplot inside the violin) is much more important as its bars tell you the 50th, 25th and 75th percentile (though the 5oth in vioplot is a white dot for some reason), and the whiskers depend on how you plot, but in the case of vioplot I think it is the 95th and 5th percentile.

If you want higher customizability, use ggplot:

```
library(reshape2) #for melt()
library(ggplot2)
uniform<-runif(200,-4,4)
normal<-rnorm(200,0,3)
df <- data.frame(x=normal, y=uniform) %>% melt()

ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot()
```

and if you want to plot all the data points instead of just the outliers, you can use ggbeeswarm for that, while not showing the outliers from geom_boxplot:

```
library(ggbeeswarm)

ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0) +
  geom_beeswarm()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that ggplot was much easier to use, and was certainly more consistent in plotting violin plots - it was also much more customizable than the vioplot() function. Thank you!